# What is the running time of precomputation for the PLONK zk-SNARK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I have been looking for benchmarks on the precomputation phase of PLONK (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf), but found none. Is there a resource where one can get a feel for this? Either in terms of CPU cycles or in terms of asymptotic complexity.

Specifically, I am trying to estimate how big of a burden it is to update the setup with new randomness for different sizes of the circuit.